# Output location of `python setup.py develop`

Tags: python, cmake, pip, setup.py

I am working with a CMake project that builds a Python extension using pybind11.

When I execute `python setup.py build` all the libraries, `.so` files, are neatly stored inside the `build` directory.
But when I execute `python setup.py develop` or `pip install -e .` all the build artifacts are spilled directly into the root folder of the project.

Is there a way to change the setup.py file to control the output location for the build artifacts? I am suspecting this has something to do with `inplace` flag.

Here's my current setup.py:

```
import os
import re
import sys
import platform
import subprocess
import multiprocessing

from setuptools import setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext
from distutils.version import LooseVersion


class CMakeExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, name, sourcedir=''):
        Extension.__init__(self, name, sources=[])
        self.sourcedir = os.path.abspath(sourcedir)


class CMakeBuild(build_ext):
    def run(self):
        try:
            subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
        except OSError:
            raise RuntimeError(
                'CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: ' +
                ', '.join(e.name for e in self.extensions),
            )

        for ext in self.extensions:
            self.build_extension(ext)

    def build_extension(self, ext):
        extdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(self.get_ext_fullpath(ext.name)))
        # required for auto-detection of auxiliary "native" libs
        if not extdir.endswith(os.path.sep):
            extdir += os.path.sep

        cmake_args = [
            f'-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY={extdir}',
            f'-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE={sys.executable}',
        ]

        cfg = 'Debug' if self.debug else 'Release'
        build_args = ['--config', cfg]

        cmake_args += [f'-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE={cfg}']
        build_args += ['--', f'-j{multiprocessing.cpu_count()}']

        env = os.environ.copy()

        if not os.path.exists(self.build_temp):
            os.makedirs(self.build_temp)

        subprocess.check_call(['cmake', ext.sourcedir] + cmake_args, cwd=self.build_temp, env=env)
        subprocess.check_call(
            ['cmake', '--build', '.', '--target', 'py_ext'] + build_args, cwd=self.build_temp,
        )


def main():
    setup(
        name='py_ext',
        version='0.0.1',
        description='py_ext',
        ext_modules=[CMakeExtension('py_ext')],
        cmdclass=dict(build_ext=CMakeBuild),
    )

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: What would be the point? Then the _editable_ install would not work, would it?

Comment: Why the location of .so files matters?
I suppose, the Python bindings library should sit in the root folder of the Python part of my codebase. So if I don't want 100 libraries in the root folder, I can just create a Python subtree and put the setup.py file there?